# how to echo mysql select result codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

i wrote the following mysql query in codeigniter

```
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT count(`leave_status`) FROM `teacher_attendance` WHERE `teacher_id`='20' AND `leave_status`='6'");
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
          $result = $query->row_array();
          print_r($result);
          echo $result;
    }
```

with echo $result; it prints nothing;
with  print_r($result); Array ( [count(`leave_status`)] => 7 ) Array like this

but how to get this value 7 to an echo?

Answer (score 3):

`$result` is an `associative` `array` you can not directly `echo` it.Access the value of `leave_status` using `$result['leave_status']`.Like below.

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT count(`leave_status`) AS leave_status FROM `teacher_attendance` WHERE `teacher_id`='20' AND `leave_status`='6'");
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
          $result = $query->row_array();
          //print_r($result);
          $total = $result['leave_status'];
          echo $total ;//prints 7
    }
```

Comment: this is the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use row() for echoing the single row result

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT count(`leave_status`) as leaveCount FROM `teacher_attendance` WHERE `teacher_id`='20' AND `leave_status`='6'");
if($query->num_rows() > 0){
      echo $query->row()->leaveCount;
}
```

refer [this link](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html) for more information

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT count(`leave_status`) as count FROM `teacher_attendance` WHERE `teacher_id`='20' AND `leave_status`='6'");

if($query->num_rows() > 0){
   foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
      echo $row['count'];
   }
}
```

Comment: i tried  echo $row->leave_status; and its prints nothing

Comment: Use alias in query. ex. "SELECT count(`leave_status`) as count"   then "echo $row->count;"

Comment: but if i  print_r($row); give this stdClass Object ( [count(`leave_status`)] => 7 )

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT count(`leave_status`) as count FROM `teacher_attendance` WHERE `teacher_id`='20' AND `leave_status`='6'");
if($query->num_rows() > 0){
      $result = $query->row_array();
      print_r($result);
      echo $result['count'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your model: **return $result**

In the controller: **$data = $this->your_model->your_function()**;

In the view: echo **$leave_status**